# How to solve "Expected identifier for type name" caused by CryptoSwift addition

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, cryptoswift

I have a codebase where I am adding CryptoSwift through pods, and after adding it it compiler has started throwing 20 odd errors of type

> Expected identifier for type name

My PodFile looks like this

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'TestApp' do
    pod 'AWSIoT'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Digits'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'PureLayout'
    pod 'Amplitude-iOS', '~> 3.11.1'
    pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.8'
    pod 'CryptoSwift'
    pod 'AWSCognitoIdentityProvider', '~> 2.5.0'
    pod 'AWSAPIGateway', '~> 2.5.0'
    pod 'AWSS3', '~> 2.5.0'
    pod 'PhoneNumberKit', '~> 1.3'
    pod 'ReachabilitySwift', '~> 3'
    pod 'libPhoneNumber-iOS', '~> 0.8'
    pod 'SVProgressHUD'
    pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 3.0'
    pod 'AwesomeCache', '~> 5.0'
    pod 'OHHTTPStubs/Swift'
    pod 'SwiftyGif'

end

target 'TestAppRecents' do
    pod 'AWSIoT'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Digits'
    pod 'CryptoSwift'
end

target ‘TestAppTests’ do
    pod 'AWSIoT'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Digits'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'PureLayout'
    pod 'Amplitude-iOS', '~> 3.11.1'
    pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.8'
    pod 'AWSCognitoIdentityProvider', '~> 2.5.0'
    pod 'AWSAPIGateway', '~> 2.5.0'
    pod 'AWSS3', '~> 2.5.0'
    pod 'PhoneNumberKit', '~> 1.3'
    pod 'ReachabilitySwift', '~> 3'
    pod 'libPhoneNumber-iOS', '~> 0.8'
    pod 'SVProgressHUD'
    pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 3.0'
    pod 'AwesomeCache', '~> 5.0'
    pod 'OHHTTPStubs/Swift'
    pod 'SwiftyGif'
end
```

Pod gets installed just fine I have added the file to point me out if any conflict 
Here is the additional info

[image]

Comment: I think you have edited this file with textedit as it has smart quote `target ‘TestAppTests’ do` try adding a normal quote?

Comment: You didn't get it problem is when pod is installed that is cryptoswift is installed pod file is working fine